# Twitter oauth/request_token 200 code with empty response body

Tags: android, kotlin, twitter, gson, retrofit

I'm implementing Twitter OAuth flows as per:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/guides/log-in-with-twitter

I am getting a response back for the first step (oauth/request_token) which has a 200 code, but the response body is completely empty.

I'm using Retrofit to call the API, and have hooked up an interceptor OkHttpClient to debug the response like so:

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().also { builder ->
    builder.addInterceptor { chain ->
        val request = chain.request()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        response
    }
}.build()
```

Then setting up Retrofit like so:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(TWITTER_AUTH_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build()
                .create(TwitterAuthRetrofit::class.java)
                .getRequestToken(
                       authorizationHeaders
                ).enqueue(object : Callback<TwitterRequestToken> {
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<TwitterRequestToken>, response: Response<TwitterRequestToken>) {
                        onSuccess(response.body())
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<TwitterRequestToken>, t: Throwable) {
                        onFailure()
                    }
                })
```

When I debug in the interceptor, I can see the response is successful (200) but the response body is empty, which I think is causing my Gson deserialization to fail.

The result of calling `response.body.contentLength()` in the interceptor is -1.

The result of calling `response.code` in the interceptor is 200.

Here is the model I am attempting to deserialize the response body to:

```
data class TwitterRequestToken(
        @SerializedName(value = "oauth_token")
        val token: String,
        @SerializedName(value = "oauth_token_secret")
        val tokenSecret: String,
        @SerializedName(value = "oauth_callback_confirmed")
        val callbackConfirmed: Boolean
)
```

Note I am using `@SerializedName` to provide the keys for the response body, whilst the names of my properties are arbitrary to our app (we use camel case). I add a `GsonConverterFactory` to the Retrofit instance using the builder and have done this in the same way for many other requests before with no issues.

Here is the response I am getting from the API, which I am looking at via debugging in the interceptor above:

```
Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token}
```

And here is the `cause` message from the  `Throwable` I am getting in the `onFailure` callback from Retrofit:

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: 
Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Has anyone got any idea what might cause this?

Comment: "which is causing my Gson deserialization to fail"; is an exception thrown? I assume Gson is throwing an EOFException because it does not permit empty JSON documents.

Comment: @Marcono1234 - An exception is not thrown, because it's "swallowed" in the Retrofit library, but I do get a callback invoked `onFailure`, where I have the `Throwable`. I will update the question with actual information about the throwable now, just need to reproduce it again.

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1554 might have multiple comments which provide solutions for this.

Comment: @Marcono1234 - Maybe, maybe not; they're all talking about when the response body is empty (which is, to be fair, what I am also seeing). But I shouldn't be seeing an empty response body with a 200 response from that API in the first place (at least according to all the official documentation I've read - see original link). I have also asked on the twitter developer support forums a similar question; but no answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, hope this helps someone in future...

The response body from the Twitter API for oauth/request_token isn't encoded as JSON; you will need to read it from the response buffer. Specifically, when implementing the API with Retrofit, you will want your Retrofit interface to return `ResponseBody` (rather than your custom class), remove GSON from the Retrofit builder and, in the `onResponseCallback` from Retrofit, write the following code to read the buffer to a string, then split the string on `&` to get each key val pair, then you can split each of these on `=` and make sure you have all 3 values before constructing your model:

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                        response.body()?.also { body ->
                            body.source().readString(Charsets.UTF_8).split('&').map { param ->
                                param.split('=').let { keyVal ->
                                    keyVal[0] to keyVal[1]
                                }
                            }.toMap().let { paramMap ->
                                val oauthToken = paramMap["oauth_token"]
                                val oauthTokenSecret = paramMap["oauth_token_secret"]
                                val oauthCallbackConfirmed = paramMap["oauth_callback_confirmed"]?.toBoolean()
                                if (oauthToken == null || oauthTokenSecret == null || oauthCallbackConfirmed == null) {
                                    onFailure()
                                } else {
                                    onSuccess(
                                            TwitterRequestToken(
                                                    oauthToken,
                                                    oauthTokenSecret,
                                                    oauthCallbackConfirmed
                                            )
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        } ?: onFailure()
                    }
```